# How do I implement bullet spread in three-dimensional space?

Tags: unity, c#

How can I shoot a bullet in three-dimensional space in such a way that its path diverges a bit, randomly, from the direction in which the gun is pointed?

I know I have to use the Quaternions, but I don't know how exactly.

[image: Three-dimensional possible directions]

Should I convert Quaternion to EulerAngles

```
Quaternion randomRotation = Random.rotation;    
Vector3 inEuler = randomRotation.eulerAngles;
```

or is there a fairer / nicer way to do it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Should I convert Quaternion to EulerAngles

No, going to EulerAngles makes most things worse.

Try something like this instead:

```
Vector3 PickFiringDirection(Vector3 muzzleForward, float spreadRadius) {
    Vector3 candidate = Random.insideUnitSphere * spreadRadius + muzzleForward;
    return candidate.normalized;
}
```

Here we pick a random vector offset to add to the end of our nominal shooting direction, then normalize it so the result is still a unit vector.

There are more ways to pick a random vector in-line with our shooting direction or only slightly deviating from it than there are to pick a highly perpendicular offset, so this will give a distribution where most shots go toward the middle of the cone, and outliers hitting the edges of the cone are more rare.

Your `spreadRadius` is roughly the radius of the cone 1 unit from the muzzle, or roughly `Mathf.Tan(Mathf.Deg2Rad * angle/2f)` where `angle` is the divergence between opposite sides of the cone.