# Adding spread to velocity Vector3D

Tags: 3d, trigonometry

I am trying to give an object a velocity spread (e.g. shotgun bullets or particle effect).

```
//dir is the initial direction
float angle1 = atan(dir.x, dir.z) + spread;
float angle2 = atan(dir.y, abs(dir.z)) + spread;
vec3 xz_dir = vec3(sin(angle1, 0.0, cos(angle2));
vec3 yz_dir = vec3(0.0, sin(angle2), cos(angle2));
vec3 new_dir = vec3(xz_dir.x * yz_dir.z, yz_dir.y, xz_dir.z * yz_dir.z);
new_dir.normalize();
```

The `new_dir` spread works fine in the XY and YZ planes but if there is a Y component in the direction, the spread along the XY plane doesn't work.

Comment: Can [this](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/169893/how-do-i-implement-bullet-spread-in-three-dimensional-space) question provide the solution to your issue?

Comment: I am trying to work with Euler angles.

I grab two angles from the direction XZ plane and YZ plane and then add a random spread. Then I convert them back into two vectors. Then I combine the two vectors to get the new direction with the added spread.

If I also add a random spread in the XY plane by first grabbing the angle, add a spread, convert to vector:
```float angle3 = atan(dir.y, dir.x) + spread;  
vec3 xy_dir vec3(cos(angle1_rad), sin(angle1_rad), 0.0);  
```
How would I add this xy vector to the other two vectors?

Comment: Euler angles will not give you the results you want here. [As illustrated here, stacking ranges of Euler angles tends to make odd shapes that are not what you intended or predicted from looking at your math](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/a/162298/39518). I'd strongly recommend throwing away Euler angles and trying a fresh approach for bullet spread.